# CLI Reflector How to store type objects that can be used by constructor

Tags: .net, generics, containers, command-line-interface, reflector

I will try to make myself as clear as i can :).
I want to implement some kind of an interpreter and i would like to be able to somehow store classes not as object but more like as blueprint which could be then used to construct instances of these classes.

exmpl.

THIS IS AN EXAMPL PROP FILE

```
[class]
   myClass
```

THIS IS AN EXAMPL PARSER FUNCTION

```
Dictionary<String^,Type>^ parserios(String^ file)
{
     /*bla bla bla parsing and we get **Dictionary<String^,Type>^** thatholds string name of class and its blueprint*/
}
```

lets make static dictionary for BaseClassOfSomeSort "**classes**" which will held results of *parserios* function;

and now constructing function

```
BaseClassOfSomeSort^ constructFunct(String^ type, array<Object^>^ args)
{
     return gcnew BaseClassOfSomeSort::classes[type](args);
}
```

I thought that it would be possible by using Type::GetType(String^) function and then just invoke gcnew on returned Type object but sadly it cannot be done this way.
So is there any way?

Comment: Use Activator::CreateInstance() instead.